# Object's float property returns inconsistent values

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects containing a float property and for some reason many of these values return and render different text to the browser (html and console) than they're actually calculated to be.

I'm not able to see any pattern in the numbers, but when the below loop is halted at the end of the first iteration, the single output *is* correct.

Can anybody advise what is causing this behaviour and how to address it?

---

Debug log:

```js
// get nearby brand colours 
for(let i=0, l=sorted.length; i<l; i++){
    sorted[i]['similar'] = floss.similar( sorted[i].hex, this.elements.colour_distance.value, this.getSelectedColourDistanceMethod() ); 
    console.log('sorted[i][\'similar\']', sorted[i]['similar']);
    console.log('JSON.stringify(sorted[i][\'similar\'])', JSON.stringify(sorted[i]['similar']));
}
return;
```

An example of an incorrect value, but the one that is used when the property is called:

[image: An example of an incorrect value, but the one that is used when the property is called]

Correct value, when displayed with `JSON.Stringify`

[image: Correct value, when displayed with JSON.Stringify]

Comment: Are you perhaps changing the values at a later stage in your app? The console will show live data for object references. I suggest you use a debugger to inspect values instead of the console

Comment: Not that I'm able to see but I'll give it another look. There's no synchronous work happening and the function is halted immediately after the above `console.log`s. For a while I thought something was wrong with the sort function until I noticed all the other properties are correct, it's just the distance value :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsurprisingly this was a pass-by-reference problem occuring *before* this point, not after.

Fixed by iterating through object properties and assigning to a new one, rather than setting result to object itself and expanding.